# how to skip incompatible architecture when linking with lld

Tags: c++, ld, lld

I have a lib that provides both `libxxx_x86_64.a` and `libxxx_arm64.a`. When linking using `ld` x86_64.a is skipped,

```
ld: warning: ignoring file _pod_work_dir/Pods/____/libs/______x86_64.a, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-x86_64
```

however lld won't do so

```
1d64.11d: error: _pod_work_dir/Pods/_____/libs/______x86_64.a(___+___.o)has architecture x86_64 which is incompatible with target architecture arm64
```

Is there an option with lld I can make this behavior a warning instead of error.

the lib is downloaded directly into build dir by cmake or pods script like this. So the project just try to link x86_64.a as well.
[image]

Comment: How are you building your app?  That's what you need to fix.

Comment: sorry I don't understand. This is linking right? how does Debug/Release affect this?

Comment: What I meant was: why is your build script (whatever that is) trying to link with both libraries, when you clearly want only one.

Comment: On Linux the libs should be /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxxx.a and /usr/lib/arm64-linux-gnu/libxxx.a (or /opt/lib/ or /usr/local/lib or whatever prefix). Then when you link -lxxx the linker will only look in one subdirectory.

Comment: I'm building on mac. It seems the pods script just add the two .a as a lib and try to linking it. those libs are downloaded into _pod_work_dir directly so it would require the script guy to do the work ...

Comment: Paul is recommending that you just link the correct one instead of both

Comment: I can only delete the x86_64.a, but it will be downloaded back when cmake re-configure

Comment: What IDE are you using there?  Doesn't look like Xcode (or have you changed the colour scheme or something?).

Comment: it's Clion. I'm in favor of configuring directly from cmake, instead of convert to xcode or vs project

Comment: Show the CMake code responsible for linking the `.a` files with your program. It can no doubt be made architecture-specific

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. It's company code and its too big! I just can't locate the code. Since there's no workaround with `lld`, I decided to ask the cmake script guy to do his work